# JMeter script that loops and increases throughput until failure

Tags: loops, jmeter, throughput, capacity

Curious if anyone has any ideas on how I might create a jmeter script that will loop the scenario while increasing throughput and load until an error is received.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the following way:

1. Set your test to run "Forever" on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level
2. Set "Action to be taken on a Sampler error" to "Stop Test"

[image: Thread Group]

3. Add a [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to your test plan with very low initial value like 60 requests per minute (= 1 request per second)
4. Despite "Constant" word in its name, Constant Throughput Timer value can be changed on-the-fly [see official documentation for example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server).